# How to calculate a line from a position and bearing in SQL Server 2012 (Spatial)

Tags: line, sql-server, sql-server-spatial, bearing, calculate-geometry

Currently I've a table filled with measurements from a certain point. All the rows contain a location in Lat/Lon, a bearing in degrees and some other data containing sensor updates etc. At this moment I'm using the "bearing distance to line tool" in ArcGIS Pro to display the data.

I'm looking for a good method to generate the lines in SQL Server (Spatial). Ultimate goal is to display large amounts of measurements without having to use the tool of ArcGIS Pro.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: How long should the lines be?

Comment: Around 15 Kilometers

Comment: What coordinate system are your Lat/Lon in?

Comment: The coordinate system is in WGS84

Comment: perhaps the geography data type can translate the LAT/LON to kilometers, but I don't know what the SQL would be to utilize the azimuth...